# How to send SMS messages from a Java Web Application

Tags: java, sms, messaging, spring-3

I need to implement a use case in which I need to auto-generate message to a new user to verify his mobile number by asking him to enter a number sent to his mobile in an SMS.

Does Spring Framework provide any integration support to implement such a use case?

Could someone suggest me how to do that?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sending SMS messages requires a gateway provider, e.g. Clickatell or Twilio or whatever. You then implement that provider's SDK to send messages.

It costs about $5k to setup a short code, and about $1500 per month to maintain it. Some providers, like Twilio, let you share a development short code for sending messages, but you can't receive any.

What I've done for verification is send a message via email to a phone, asking for the phone number and the provider. Then convert that into the phone's email address, e.g. 9785551234@vtext.com.

Comment: additionally, to determine the email address for an operator, get a subscriber to send a text to your email - works like a charm!

Comment: Yeah @KevinDTimm - I actually use a table of provider email addresses. I wonder too if Google Voice has an API for sending texts?

Comment: @Matt H & KavinDTimm: I don't want to ask the new user for any other information apart from his mobile phone number. I've been trying to test Clickatell but it doesn't seem to work at my network as I din't receive any activation code from them. I am not sure if Twilio  provides services in Asia as well. I am wondering if there is an opensource API. I am trying to do something that Google does when it asks for your mobile number for security issues. I am wondering if there is an spring integration support already to achieve just that.

Comment: @skip I've personally used OpenMarket for SMS messaging. OpenMarket is quite nice, and I used it with US, Canada, Mexico, Europe, India and Brazil phone numbers and carriers.

Comment: @Matt H: I'll get back to it once I am done with what I was trying to implement. Thanks for you reply.